# adding a (left or right) sidebar with underscores

Tags: sidebar

I recently installed underscores but all the content supposed to be in the right sidebar (set with a widget) is under the main content: [https://test.sacconicase.com/case-vacanza/italia/toscana/marina-di-massa-appartamenti-vacanze/]
What I have to add to sidebar.php or to any other file?

Comment: underscores is a barebones starter theme, it doesn't provide a sidebar or an underscores specific way of adding one, you have to implement it yourself

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to register your sidebar with `register_sidebar()`, if you haven't done it already. You can find a basic [example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/#comment-366) on the function's documentation.

To render the sidebar area within your sidebar template file use `dynamic_sidebar()`. You can wrap that in `if` statement with `is_active_sidebar()`, if the sidebar should only be displayed when it has one or more widgets assigned to it. Have a look at the documentation for another [example](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dynamic_sidebar/#comment-424).

The theme developers handbook also has a nice chapter on [sidebars](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/sidebars/).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. First of all underscores has already by default a sidebar registered, its own file sidebar.php, so I was told the only thing I had to do was adding some css, in particular a % for the primary container and a % (balance) for the secondary, and than use a float

```
#primary {width:75%;;float:left} #secondary{width:25%; 
float:left;}
```

After that I realised that I had to specify the screen device because also on mobiles the site was broken into 2 parts so I used

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px)
```

Comment: But I'm having problems with the sticky header, I was told it's because of the floating of the 2 containers :(